# What does 'everyone' imply in Heb 2:9 ...that He might taste death for everyone

Tags: jesus, soteriology, death

> Heb 2:9 But we do see Him who was made for a little while lower than
> the angels, namely, Jesus, because of the suffering of death crowned
> with glory and honour, so that by the grace of God He **might taste
> death for everyone.**

1. Jesus death has covered ALL
2. We know from 2 Peter 3:9 that there is a 'desire' to save all.

> The LORD is not slow in keeping his promise, as some
> understand slowness. Instead he is patient with you, **not wanting
> anyone to perish**, but **everyone** to come to repentance.

We also understand that as God grants repentance, the ball is in His court to call all eventually.

> John 12:32 And I, if I be lifted up from the earth, will draw **all men**
> unto me.

I'd prefer not to deviate to a fruitless discussion about hell - mostly because that is not what the verse(s) is talking about. As God is called Saviour (Isaiah 43:11++), the name implies he saves! God's glory is what He says and accomplishes - not what He gets a passing grade for by saving most.

So essentially, we know **all** are covered, but it appears **all** are 'potentially' saved too.

Does 'everyone' potentially mean EVERYONE?
Or to put it another way, If Jesus 'tasted **death** for everyone', then everyone will **live** in him too.

---

> Is 55:11 So will My word be which goes forth from My mouth; It will
> not return to Me empty, Without accomplishing what I desire, And
> without succeeding in the matter for which I sent it.

When God calls someone, and He will call all in one time or another before the end of all ends, He doesn't do so with a 1/2 hearted wish. He does it with intent and with power and expects results according to His will - His heavenly will. Having accomplished the 'process' through Jesus, the rest is the easy bit.

Comment: Matthew 22.  The kingdom of heaven is like a wedding feast fully prepared but those who were called were not willing to come and were deemed unworthy.  This does not lessen the preparation or intent of the King who prepared the feast and it does not invalidate the desire behind the invitation.

Comment: Christ's (obviously) suffered death with His human nature, thus enabling all men with the potential to rip its benefits (becoming dead to sin and temptation). The same also applies to the resurrection.

Answer (score 3):

The immediate context which follows and to which the phrase 'for every one he might taste death' (Englishman's Greek New Testament, interlinear - υπερ παντος γευσηται θανατου) is that of :

> ... in bringing many sons to glory ... verse 10

> ... he that sanctifieth and they who are sanctified ... verse 11

> ... I will declare thy name unto my brethren ... verse 12

> ... in the midst of the church will I sing praise ... verse 12

> ... Behold I and the children which God hath given me ... verse 13

What is in view is the ascended Christ and what is - now - under his Headship. And also what is in view is the rearrangement of creation as Christ ascends above angels to sit in the throne of God, all things (verse 8) being put under his feet.

But not 'all' is under his feet. 'But now we see not yet all things put under him' (verse 8)  relates to the entirety of creation and the enemies who have not submitted to him, in the heavens and upon earth. 'Sit thou until I make thine enemies thy footstool' is said to the risen and ascended Christ, Psalm 110:1, Matthew 22:44, Acts 2:34, Hebrews 1:13 and 1 Corinthians 15: 24, 25.

'All' in creation is not yet under him.

But 'all' that is under his Headship, all the sons destined for glory (v10) all the sanctified (v11) all the brethren (v12) all the church (v12) all the children (v13) are all subject to his present reign from the throne of God.

It is true that the Lamb of God taketh away the sin of the world - the liability of that which entered creation by conspiracy of serpent, woman and man.

But the 'tasting of death for everyone', here spoken of, clearly relates - in context - to that which is **under the Headship** of one risen in manhood and ascended into the heavens to rule above the angels whilst time runs its course and enemies still reject him .... *until all things are put under him.*

Answer (score 1):

The idea that Jesus' salvation is extended to all people everywhere is a very common theme in Scripture:

- John 1:29, “Behold the Lamb of God who takes away the sin of the world.”
- John 3:16, “God so loved the world that He gave …”
- John 12:32, “I [Jesus] … will draw all people to myself.”
- Acts 17:30, “God … commands all people everywhere to repent.”
- Rom 3:23, 24, “… for all have sinned … and all are freely forgiven...”
- Rom 5:8, 10, “… while we were still sinners, Christ died for us. … if, while were God’s enemies, we were reconciled to him by the death of His Son, …”
- Rom 5:15, “But the free gift is not like the offense. For if by the one man’s [Adam’s] offense many died, much more the grace of God and the gift by the grace of the one Man, Jesus Christ, abounded to the many.”  [Note the same word, “many” applies to all people.]
- Rom 5:18, “Therefore, as through one man’s offense judgment came to all people, resulting in condemnation, even so through one Man’s righteous act the free gift came to all people, resulting in justification of life.”
- Rom 11:32, “For God has imprisoned everyone in disobedience so that He may show mercy to all.”
- 2 Cor 5:14, “…we are convinced that one died for all, and therefore all died.”
- 2 Cor 5:18, 19, “…God was reconciling the world to Himself in Christ …”
- 1 Tim 2:3, 4, “For this is good and acceptable in the sight of God our Saviour, who desires all men to be saved and to come to the knowledge of the truth.”
- 1 Tim 2:6, “[Jesus Christ] gave Himself as a ransom for all people.”
- Titus 2:11, “For the grace of God appeared bringing salvation to all people.”
- Heb 2:9, “But we see Jesus, who was made a little lower than the angels, now crowned with glory and honour because he suffered death, so that by the grace of God he might taste death for everyone.”
- 2 Peter 3:9, “The Lord is not slow in keeping his promise, as some understand slowness.  He is patient with you, not wanting anyone to perish, but everyone to come to repentance.”
- 1 John 2:2, “He Himself [Jesus] is the propitiation for our sins, and not for ours [Christians to whom John writes] only but also for the whole world.”
- Isa 53:6, “We all like sheep have gone astray … and the LORD has laid on him the iniquity of us all.”

Thus, Jesus atonement provided by His sacrifice is offered to all people.  God wants to save everyone.  However, not everyone will or does accept this offer - many will be lost by a personal choice.

Thus, while Jesus atonement is universal, salvation is not universal.  God wants to save, pleads to save, begs to save all people but some refuse.  God initiates salvation because God provided atonement for all "while we were still sinners (Rom 5:6-8).

Rom 3:25-28 tells us that God did this to prove that He is righteous, but that is another story again and not for this question.

It is Rom 6:23 that tells us that "the wages of sin is death but the gift of God is eternal life in Jesus Christ our Lord."  Therefore, as sinners we deserve to die but Christ died for us (Rom 5:6-8) so that we can be saved, but only if we want it.

Comment: Yes. However, you have not considered that as God is called Saviour, losing ONE is going to take the shine off. That means the devil wins that soul and God lost.  I will edit to add more to this aspect.

Comment: @user48152 - OK but exactly what are you asking?  I have answered the only question in your OP.  Make your question (not a mere statement) clearer.  Jesus said He lost one (Judas) as well!

Comment: @Dottard You say,"Jesus' salvation is extended to all people", and you say "salvation is not universal". By "all people" do you mean all people groups i.e. not just Jews?

Comment: @C.Stroud - Salvation is extended to all people but that does not mean all are saved because each person must accept in some sense.  No one is saved against their will.

Comment: @Dottard And part of the salvation process is being given that willingness?

Comment: @C.Stroud - I fully agree - not only does God provide atonement, but also the desire to be saved.  However, some resist.  The subject of this question is only the death of Jesus.

Answer (score 0):

I begin my answer with a caveat. This view is not supported by traditional doctrine, but I provide it for consideration. So you need to ‘test’ this!
Jesus died for the ‘sin’ of the world. That ‘sin’, that transgression of the Law that demands to be judged. So essentially that judgement that ‘sin’ demanded, namely ‘death’, was ‘paid for’ - for everyone. So far, most may agree.
Now for that ‘other’ part. You are not condemned to ‘hell’ for ‘sin’. People won’t ‘go to hell’ for their ‘sin’. Sin isn’t the issue. Just like people won’t go to heaven for being sin-less.

OK, let’s put the term ‘hell’ into correct perspective, because people (some theologians included.) have let their reasoning/imagination dominate.

Man is born separated from God. And, God is the source of Love, peace, joy, life. Now, man has learnt to source these, to varying degrees, from the world. But, you need a [physical] body to do so - but what about if you ‘lose’ the use of your ‘body’[death]. You will still ‘be’, everybody is eternal, but can’t access joy, peace love none of those ‘needs’ your soul wants. That’s ‘hell’.

But, believers have a source for these needs, because they have been reunited with God. And more, believers also get a resurrected [new] body, so will also be able interact with ‘the world’.
But now, back to your query. Believers have eternal ‘life’ (as opposed to eternal death/separation.) through Righteousness - God righteousness. And this is a gift, that comes by choice.

The fact that all ‘sin’ has been paid for doesn’t give man ‘Life’ (although it’s crucial in that it redeems us. I am not diminishing in any way at all the need for Jesus’s sacrifice for our sin!!!!), But, that doesn’t ‘get’ you eternal ‘Life’. The ‘thing’ that makes the difference, that makes one ‘a Christian’, is that you have been made righteous.

Now some will argue that this is what ‘getting rid of sin’ is all about. But those same people have issues with ‘Lot’ being called righteous, and Abraham being seen as righteous even though he lied, etc. But, righteousness has never been able to be attained by man, through what man ‘does’, or doesn’t do, nor however ‘clean’ ‘he’ becomes. No, Righteousness comes from God, and, it’s a gift. And you can receive it irrespective of anything.

And yes, believers need to be ‘clean’ because their ‘body’ is a temple, and as well,’sin’ in the flesh will ‘attract’ judgement. But, being ‘clean’ is not what give you eternal Life’.

People will experience ‘hell’ [separation] because they choose to rely on/ stay with their own righteousness, instead of accepting Gods, through Jesus.
AND that, righteousness, was made available to us by Jesus’s Life (not Death.) - his obedience.

It’s all about righteousness - not ‘sin’[verb]. - And this is for your consideration - not necessarily acceptance.

Comment: yep, mostly accept the 'concept' you have outlined. However, you may need to define, "everybody is eternal". Which I would expect numerous scripture to deny. No one is 'eternal until the resurrection. (not even Jesus) Although it doesn't really address the 'everybody' Q - not clearly anyway...

Comment: Everyone is eternal. Man is an eternal being. Man is a ‘spirit being’ who ‘lives’ in a body. Many equate the word ‘eternal’  with/to eternal ‘Life’. But there is also ‘eternal ‘death’. Death (biblically) means separation, so *eternally* ‘dead’ means *eternally* separated (from God). Where-as believers are/will be eternally with God. That is, Alive/Life.

Comment: ok, thx. I wont bother responding to that fallacy. Otherwise, some valuable input.

Comment: Curiosity? I’m not looking to start a debate, nor advocate/support anything I said, but what fallacy are you pointing to?

Comment: yr last comment re. everyone is eternal/Man is a ‘spirit being. Without Christ they are forever dead..